# How to load torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder into google colab ram

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I'm noticing during training on google colab that getting through the first several thousand images is very fast but after that the training becomes slower.  I've timed other parts of the training to see if they are causing the problem but their time remains consistent even as the training slows down.  I believe that it is because the images are not getting stored in the ram of google colab and it has to keep pulling images from within google drive which is slower.  I also noticed that in re-running the training, the method processes the images that were previously processed very fast but then slows when it reaches images that were not processed by the previous run of the method.

I've trained on colab before using numpy arrays loading my data like this:

`train_val_images = np.load("/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/datasets/train_data.npy")`

I notice when I do this that the ram in use in the notebook increases exactly by the size of the numpy array that I am loading.

In my new project I am trying to use dataloaders and torchvision datasets instead of the numpy arrays like this:

`train_dataset = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(root="/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/datasets/labeled_data/train", transform = transforms.ToTensor())`

`trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset)`

when I load the data this way I notice that the ram in use doesn't really increase.  I am loading roughly 20,000 images from my google drive this way.

I am wondering if there is a way to load the data into the google colab ram like is done when np.load() with the torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder or if there is an another alternative where I still get to use the ImageFolder interface.

Comment: DataLoader doesn't load all the images at once. When you iterate through the dataloader, it will load one batch at a time (so the amount of memory used depends on your batch size, which you don't mention).

Comment: I tried to vary the batch size and I got some speed up although it was not significant.  Is there a way to load the ImageFolder into ram, that way when the data loader queries the dataset it is retrieving from ram?

Comment: There is a `num_workers` parameter in DataLoader. That helps in multi-processing, like multiple threads on the CPU will work on dataloading and that will kind of improve the runtime. I am not aware of any method to load the dataset into RAM (maybe asking on PyTorch forum will be more helpful).